# JavaScript math, loops inside loops

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, math

I've a starting number, so that number must be multiplied, only at starting cycle, by a factor, then the results multiplied X times for another factor, then the cycle must be multiplied for Y times, and at the end I need to have the total sum ... I think that is better to see the numbers to see what I need to have

For example if I start with the number 10, this is the right progression:

- 10
- 50 (10*5)
- 60 (50*1.2)
- 72 (60*1.2)
- 86.4 (72*1.2)
- 103.68 (86.4*1.2)
- 124.416 (103.68*1.2)

For me the first 6 is the inner cycle from now on, I need to replicate the proces but I had to use the last value, 124.416 multiplied by 5 then for 1.2 again, so

- 622.08 (124.416*5)
- 746.496 (622.08*1.2)
- 895.7952 (746.496*1.2)
- 1074.95424 (895.7952*1.2)
- 1289.94509 (1074.95424*1.2)
- 1547.93411 (1289.94509*1.2)
- 1857.52093 (1547.93411*1.2)

and so on ...

And at the end I need to sum all this intermediate results, 10 + 50 + 60 + 72 ...

I tried to do this, but is not what I need, the inner cycle works like exposed but when I add the outter cycle everythings goes wrong!

```
outtercycle = 5;
base = 10;
mult1 = 5;
mult2 = 1.2;
innercycle = 6;

aaa = 0;
number = 0;

function test()
{
    for (j = 0; j < outtercycle; j++) {
        aaa = base * mult1;
        number += aaa;
        for (i = 0; i < (innercycle - 1); i++) {
            aaa *= mult2;
            number += aaa;
        }
    }
return number + base;
}

base = test();
```

On the code I need to have 5 outter cycles, but I'm testing it only on 2, It's the same I think, when this works, works with any variable values, right?

Any idea about this little problem?

Comment: It would help if a) You didnt reuse the variable `base` both inside and outside the function and b) used meaningful variable names instead of `aaa`

Comment: Are you sure you want to start each outer cycle with `aaa = base * mult1;`? Sounds more like you should initialise `aaa = base` outside the loops and use `aaa *= mult1` in the outer cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Break this into two steps - its easier to wrap your head round.

1. Accumulate all the values in an array
2. Sum all the numbers in the array

---

```js
function getValues(start, outerCycle, outerMulti, innerCycle, innerMulti){
   var result = [start];
   var idx = 0;
   for(var i = 0;i<outerCycle;i++){
       result.push(result[idx] * outerMulti);
       idx++;
       for(var j=0;j<innerCycle;j++){
           result.push(result[idx] * innerMulti);
           idx++;
       }
   }
   return result;
}

var values = getValues(10,2,5,5,1.2);
console.log('values', values);
var sum = values.reduce(function(a,b){ return a + b; });
console.log('sum', sum);
```

Comment: Wow, amazing result, I never came up to this solution! Tnx

Answer (score 1):

You could use a single loop with an array for the factor.

```js
function getValues(value, factor, loops) {
    var array = [value], i;
    for (i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
        value *= factor[+!!i]; // +!!i returns 0 if 0 otherwise 1
        array.push(value);
    }
    return array;
}

var values= getValues(10, [5, 1.2], 6),
    sum = values.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);

console.log(values);
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion:

```js
function values(seed, cycles, notFirstRun) {
  var mult1 = 5, mult2 = 1.2, result = [];

  if (!notFirstRun) result.push(seed);  
  result.push(seed * mult1);  

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    result.push(result[result.length-1] * mult2);
  }
  if (cycles > 1) {
    result = result.concat(values(result[result.length-1], cycles-1, true));
  }
  return result;
}

var r = values(10,2)
console.log('r: ', r);
var sum = r.reduce(function(a, b){return a+b;});
console.log('sum:', sum);

var r = values(10,5)
console.log('r: ', r);
var sum = r.reduce(function(a, b){return a+b;});
console.log('sum:', sum);
```

Or, simplyfing in a single function:

```js
function mySum(seed, cycles, notFirstRun) {
  var mult1 = 5, mult2 = 1.2, result = [];

  if (!notFirstRun) result.push(seed);  
  result.push(seed * mult1);  

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    result.push(result[result.length-1] * mult2);
  }
  if (cycles > 1) {
    result = result.concat(mySum(result[result.length-1], cycles-1, true));
  }
  if (notFirstRun) {
    return result;
  } else {
    return result.reduce(function(a, b){return a+b;});
  }
}

var s = mySum(10,2)
console.log('sum: ', s);

s = mySum(10,5)
console.log('sum: ', s);
```